# GZIP google big query response using python api client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gzip, google-bigquery

How do I get the query response gzipped when I am using python api client for Google Big Query ?

Here is the code snippet :

```
jobData = {'configuration':
                         ......
                          }

jobCollection = self.service.jobs()
insertResponse = jobCollection.insert(projectId=project_id,
                                     body=jobData).execute()
queryResponse = jobCollection.getQueryResults(
        projectId=project_id,
        jobId=insertResponse['jobReference']['jobId'],
        startIndex=currentRow).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to gzip the json response after the query is complete? Or are you trying to gzip a table you created using a query result? In either case you can easily gzip a json file on your server or export a query result table google storage, then download and gzip.

Comment: I am trying to get a gzipped response from the big query api.